# how to switch between authenticated user and anonymous user in Djnango

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have this kind of view in my web application. and i have two main kids of users which are the suppliers and the admin, i am also trying to make the application usable by normal user but some functions will be restricted, i have made all the functions for the suppliers and admin and was working on the anonymous users. I have a line of code in my view dependent on the `request.user`, i still want the anonymous users to have access to that page but there is a button in form of an icon which has a `login_required` decorator, so they will have to login.

views.py

```
def products(request):
    title = "All Products"

    all_products = Product.objects.annotate(
        favourited_by_user=Count(Case(
            When(
                is_favourite=request.user,
                then=1
            ),
            # default=0,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        )),
    ).order_by('-id')

    context = {"all_products":all_products, "title":title}

    return render(request, 'core/products.html', context)
```

For the `is_favourite`, what kind of logic can i make for the anonymous users.

Comment: Where is the view that the decorator?

Comment: i don't understand please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an if-else for the annotation:

```
def products(request):
    title = "All Products"

    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        all_products = all_products.annotate(
            favourited_by_user=Count(Case(
                When(
                    is_favourite=request.user,
                    then=1
                ),
                # default=0,
                output_field=BooleanField(),
            )),
        ).order_by('-id')
    else:
        all_products = all_products.order_by('-id')
    context = {"all_products":all_products, "title":title}

    return render(request, 'core/products.html', context)
```

If I remember correctly you allow users to favourite / unfavourite on this page. You would have to write some condition for that in the template also Simplest would be to simply hide the button by putting the form inside an if block:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    form here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, i was able to solve it with your solution. instead of using a condition for the form, i already placed the @login_required decorator on the view that handles the form, so if a user clicks on it, i redirects them to the login page.

Comment: is there a way to show a mee=ssage to the user upon landing on the login page, that they have to be logged in before having the ability to favourite/unfavourite any products.

Comment: @coderboy instead of using the `login_required` you can make your own decorator, inside it use the message framework to [add a message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates) if not logged in.

Comment: Also Sir, i know Django have this particular feature such that if a user is not loggged and wan to perform something that requires him/her to be logged in, the url takes him to the login page but redirects that user to that functionailty immediately after loggin in. I don't know why it doesn't work in my application.

Comment: For example something like this, http://localhost:8001/login/?next=/add-favourite/18/ i am supposed to redirect there after login but it doesn't work, it only redirects me to the homepage.

Comment: @coderboy actually redirecting implies making a GET request, while you add a favourite using a POST request (not appropriate to make changes to data with a GET request). A better thing would be to redirect to the same point where they clicked this with an id, something like `localhost:8001/login/?next=/same-as-form-page/#some-element-id`. This would imply you making a unique id on all tags. (perhaps the products id itself along with some extra words)

Comment: how can i do that sir